# unstable wifi connection

Tags: wireless

I have a new latitude 5450 with ubuntu 14.04 and Intel 7265 wireless card. My problem is that the wifi connection is unstable and sometimes is does not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

14.04 ships with an old version of the driver.
Try to update your driver / firmware. Take a look at https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi/core_release